# Ошибка отсутствия .Net 6

Tags: c#, linux, .net, jetbrains

столкнулся с проблемой, установил .NET 6.0.12, написал программу, скомпилировал, открываю исполняемый файл просто не открывается, открываю его через терминал:
[image: проблема.пнг]

Вопрос: почему не открывается исполняемый файл(в винде он .exe), когда dotNet-6.0.22 есть и на нем написана программа

Comment: `dotnet --version`

Comment: bash: dotnet: команда не найдена

Comment: в этом и проблема, это означает дотнет рантайм не установлен, есть еще команда `dotnet --list-runtimes`, пригодится в будущем

Comment: не понимаю как не установлен) программа на нем и в jetbrains rider выбран net6.0

Comment: rider здесь не при чем, вообще

Comment: хорошо, подскажи пожалуйста, как мне установить именно дотнет рантайм?

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/install/linux-ubuntu